# What are the "humpty" and "dumpty" points?

Tags: geometry, terminology

Apologies if this isn't the right place to answer this. What are the HM points and their isogonal conjugates, also known as the Humpty and Dumpty points? I found some information via a google search, but there wasn't much on line that was a comprehensive overview. I ask, now, for a short list of properties of these points.

I am asking this because I came across an old USAMO problem (2008/2) and a friend told me it was very easy by noticing that a point (F) was in fact that A-dumpty point. This made me curious, so I decided to ask for some resources here.

thanks for your time.

Comment: I'd never heard of this before, but my first two google hits pulled up https://pregatirematematicaolimpiadejuniori.files.wordpress.com/2018/05/two_special_points__1_.pdf and https://www.awesomemath.org/wp-pdf-files/math-reflections/mr-2017-02/article_1_a_special_point_on_the_median.pdf which seem to give a comprehensive overview, albeit not "a short list of properties".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from Kapil Pause's note ["On Two Special Points in a Triangle" (PDF link via wordpress.com)](https://pregatirematematicaolimpiadejuniori.files.wordpress.com/2018/05/two_special_points__1_.pdf)

> **Humpty point.**
>
> Definition 1. In $\triangle ABC$ the $A$-Humpty point $P_A$ is defined to be a point inside triangle such that $\angle P_ABC = \angle P_AAB$ and $\angle P_ACB = \angle P_AAC$.
>
> Facts about $P_A$:
>
> 1. lies on $A$ median of $\triangle ABC$
> 2. lies on $A$ appolonius circle of $\triangle ABC$; that is, $\frac{AB}{AC} =\frac{P_AB}{P_AC}$.
> 3. $B$, $P_A$, $H$, $C$ are concyclic, where $H$ is the orthocentre of $\triangle ABC$.
> 4. $HP_A \perp AP_A$
>
> **Dumpty point.**
>
> Definition 2. In $\triangle ABC$, the $A$-Dumpty point $Q_A$ is defined to be a point inside [the] triangle such that $\angle Q_ABA = \angle Q_AAC$ and $\angle Q_AAB = \angle Q_ACA$.
>
> Facts about $Q_A$:
>
> 1. lies on $A$ symmedian
> 2. It is the centre of spiral symilarity [sic] sending $\triangle A_QAC$ to $\triangle CQ_AB$; ie, sending $AC$ to $BA$.
> 3. $B$, $Q_A$, $O$, $C$ are concyclic where $O$ is circumcentre of $\triangle ABC$.
> 4. $OQ_A \perp AQ_A$
>
> Also notice that the Humpty Dumpty points are isogonal conjugates of each other.
>
> We recommend you to try to prove these facts by yourself. This will help you in befriending the humpty-dumpty points well

Back to your question, which is also addressed in Pause's note:

> Question: (USAMO 2008). $ABC$ is a triangle. $M$, $N$ are respectively the midpoints of $AB$, $AC$. The perpendicular bisector of $AB$, $AC$ meet the $A$ median at $D$, $E$ respectively. $BD$ and $CE$ meet at $F$. Prove that $A$, $M$, $F$, $N$ are concyclic.
>
> Proof: Ah, yes $F$ is none other than the $A$−Dumpty point of $ABC$. To reach
> the desired conclusion, see that $OF\perp AF$, $ON \perp AC$, $OM \perp AB$ directly implies $A$, $M$, $O$, $N$, $F$ are concyclic with $AO$ as diameter. Another way to finish would have been to see that since a spiral similiarity centered at $F$ maps $AC$ to $BA$, it also maps the midpoint of $AB$ to midpoint of $AC$ that is, $M$ to $N$. The angle of spiral
> similarity is $\angle AFC$ which is $180^\circ − A$, and this must also be the $\angle MFN$ and we finish.

Comment: I have added a link to the source of the text of your solution, to provide proper credit. (I also cleaned-up some formatting.) Please refrain from simply copy-pasting other people's work and presenting it as if it is your own (as you also appear to have done with [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3894688/409)). Plagiarism is bad!